# Unable to fully create index in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, curl, put

I am new to elasticsearch so sorry is this is a newbie question :-)

I have read the documentation,and I'm trying to create an index.

```
curl -X PUT -x "" "http://127.0.0.1:9200"/test2 { "mappings": { "_doc": { "prope
rties": { "user" : { "type": "keyword" } } } } }
```

But i get this:

```
{"acknowledged":true,"shards_acknowledged":true,"index":"test2"}curl: (3) unmatc
hed brace in URL position 1:
{
 ^
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: mappings
curl: (3) unmatched brace in URL position 1:
{
 ^
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: _doc
curl: (3) unmatched brace in URL position 1:
{
 ^
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: properties
curl: (3) unmatched brace in URL position 1:
{
 ^
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: user
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>405 Method Not Allowed</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Method Not Allowed</h1>
<p>The requested method PUT is not allowed for the URL /index.html.</p>
</body></html>
curl: (3) unmatched brace in URL position 1:
{
 ^
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: type
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: keyword
curl: (3) unmatched close brace/bracket in URL position 1:
}
 ^
curl: (3) unmatched close brace/bracket in URL position 1:
}
 ^
curl: (3) unmatched close brace/bracket in URL position 1:
}
 ^
curl: (3) unmatched close brace/bracket in URL position 1:
}
 ^
curl: (3) unmatched close brace/bracket in URL position 1:
}
 ^
```

If i run `curl -X GET  -x  "" "http://127.0.0.1:9200"/test`

I get:

```
{"test":{"aliases":{},"mappings":{},"settings":{"index":{"creation_date":"155119
5109041","number_of_shards":"5","number_of_replicas":"1","uuid":"WNIucwr0T8aniZk
PrVLoNA","version":{"created":"6060099"},"provided_name":"test"}}}}
```

Snapshot(of terminal 1(I cut it to half because there was no sapce):

[image: Snapshot 1 of terminal]

Snapshot2:

[image: Snapshot2]

I am mostly confused because:

- It `acknowledges:true` then suddenly stops interpreting the code
- All the braces are properly matched,so I don't understand why it says `unmatched brace`

Thanks.

Comment: Again, look at the double quotes `"http://127.0.0.1:9200"/test2`. no good!

Answer (score 0):

The correct curl command on Windows is the following one:

```
curl -X PUT "http://127.0.0.1:9200/test2" -d "{ \"mappings\": { \"_doc\": { \"properties\": { \"user\" : { \"type\": \"keyword\" } } } } }"
```

Comment: Oh hi val.Remember me?

Comment: I think there needs to be a small `-x` after `PUT`

Comment: `The requested URL could not be retrieved` basically and html code

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of your terminal in your question?

Comment: Then it means your ES server is not up and running, verify that first

Comment: But when I run:
`curl -X GET -x "" "http://127.0.0.1:9200"`,I  get the exact same thing when I open http://localhost:9200

Comment: you should remove the Squid cache you have, that would facilitate the resolution of the issue, and not use the `-x` switch